# Can't migrate properly a column in a Django database. Anyone know why?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-migrations

So I'm working on a Django project and I did some changes to my `user.py` model. I simply added a boolean value to it. When I run the `manage.py makemigrations <my app>` everything runs smoothly, but when I run `manage.py migrate` it crashes and displays de following error:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: ""is_admin""

Which I find odd because it is on my model file and I even got to make the `manage.py makemigrations <my app>` command properly. Does anyone know what's going on? If it makes it more clear I can put the whole error in the comments but I didn't want to add it here since it's very long.

I even tried changing the name of my attribute but it doesn't seem to matter. The error still says "is_admin" is not a column. I've tried commenting/deleting the line of code in the `model` and run the migrations again but it seems kinda stuck on that error.

Comment: Share the changes you made (so perhaps the model in `users.py` as well as perhaps the "diff" with the previous commit if you have this)

Comment: Hi! I tried this but still no luck :/ what concerns me is I even changed the column's name and the error is still focused on the "is_admin" column.